# ERROR : 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet' --> Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have code which should convert all CSV files inside a folder to excel sheets  using python , but when i am running the code am getting "'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'"

below is my code :

```
import glob
import xlwt
import csv
import os

dest = r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pylenium-test\Results'
workbook = xlwt.Workbook(dest+"/Combined.xlsx")
counter = 0
for csv_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(dest+"/", '*.csv')):
   sheet_name = 'Sheet_' + str(counter)
   counter += 1

   worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
   with open(csv_file, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f)
      for r, row in enumerate(reader):
          for c, col in enumerate(row):
              worksheet.write(r, c, col)
      workbook.close()
```

Comment: Apparently `Workbook` objects have no attribute `add_worksheet` -- so don't try to use an attribute that doesn't exist. Look at the documentation for the library that you are using to see what you can use instead (perhaps simply `add_sheet`?).

Comment: simply an addsheet gives me an error , so when i searched it asked me to use xlwt , and i used it , but still am getting this error

Comment: `add_sheet` is a method for the workbook class, so if you get an error it isn't the *same* error. If you have a question about how to use a method which actually exists, perhaps you could ask a new question (or edit this one, including its title).